# Is the rotational velocity of a vortex consistent across its height?

Tags: velocity, rotation, vortex

I am trying to locate information about calculating the rotational velocity of a vortex. Is the velocity at the vertex maintained across the entire vertical height of the vortex? As the radius increases toward the top of the vortex, does the period of rotation match that of the vertex or is it faster/slower?

Thank you in advance.